# Selecting languages with specific ISO code

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I want to retrieve the full language name given an isocode language abbreviation. My SPARQL query is as follows (with hard-coded language `"fr"@en`):

```
PREFIX dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT ?language ?isocode
WHERE
{ ?language dbpprop:iso ?isocode.
  ?language a dbo:Language.
  FILTER (?isocode="fr"@en)
}
```

Running it through the online [DBPedia endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) yields zero results — though I expect to retrieve "French".   This code used to work a year or two ago (if I am not totally mistaken). Since no errors pop up, I am a bit at a loss. The [French language](http://dbpedia.org/page/French_language) DBPedia resource contains both the language and iso property.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than filtering, you can just search for the languages you want directly. E.g.:

```
SELECT ?language WHERE {
  ?language dbpprop:iso "fr"@en .
  ?language a dbpedia-owl:Language .
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20?language%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20?language%20dbpprop%3aiso%20%22fr%22@en%20.%0D%0A%20%20?language%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3aLanguage%20.%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

The results are

```
language
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Canadian_French
http://dbpedia.org/resource/New_England_French
http://dbpedia.org/resource/French_language
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Colonial_French
```

If you do want the `?isocode` variable bound to `"fr"@en`, you can use a `VALUES` clause to specify (and others, too, if you want).  E.g.:

```
SELECT ?language ?isocode
WHERE {
  VALUES ?isocode { "fr"@en "fro"@en "fra"@en }
  ?language dbpprop:iso ?isocode .
  ?language a dbpedia-owl:Language .
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20?language%20?isocode%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20VALUES%20?isocode%20%7B%20%22fr%22@en%20%22fro%22@en%20%22fra%22@en%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20?language%20dbpprop%3aiso%20?isocode%20.%0D%0A%20%20?language%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3aLanguage%20.%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

If you really do want to filter, you can still do that too.  E.g.:

```
SELECT ?language ?isocode
WHERE {
  ?language dbpprop:iso ?isocode .
  ?language a dbpedia-owl:Language .
  FILTER ( str(?isocode) = "fr" && langMatches( lang(?isocode), "EN" ) )
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20?language%20?isocode%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20?language%20dbpprop%3aiso%20?isocode%20.%0D%0A%20%20?language%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3aLanguage%20.%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28%20str%28?isocode%29%20=%20%22fr%22%20&&%20langMatches%28%20lang%28?isocode%29,%20%22EN%22%20%29%20%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your links work for me. Never mind what I just wrote, it all works!

Comment: @Claudia glad to hear it! If it answers your question, do consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to let other users know that it worked.